# How to increase performance for converting docx to pdf in Microsoft Graph Api

Tags: c#, .net, azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

We are doing a docx-PDF conversion by uploading a Word-document(docx) by first uploading it using the large document upload in Microsoft Graph API ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/large-file-upload?tabs=csharp)) and after that downloading it to PDF-format ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get_content_format?view=odsp-graph-online)). However, the whole process (upload + download) takes around 10-15s (file sizes around 5-15 MB) to complete and we would like to know if there are any possibilities to improve the performance?

Code sample from Microsoft for the file upload:

```
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
{
    // Use properties to specify the conflict behavior
    // in this case, replace
    var uploadProps = new DriveItemUploadableProperties
    {
        ODataType = null,
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "replace" }
        }
    };

    // Create the upload session
    // itemPath does not need to be a path to an existing item
    var uploadSession = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root
        .ItemWithPath(itemPath)
        .CreateUploadSession(uploadProps)
        .Request()
        .PostAsync();

    // Max slice size must be a multiple of 320 KiB
    int maxSliceSize = 320 * 1024;
    var fileUploadTask =
        new LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem>(uploadSession, fileStream, maxSliceSize);

    // Create a callback that is invoked after each slice is uploaded
    IProgress<long> progress = new Progress<long>(prog => {
        Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded {prog} bytes of {fileStream.Length} bytes");
    });

    try
    {
        // Upload the file
        var uploadResult = await fileUploadTask.UploadAsync(progress);

        if (uploadResult.UploadSucceeded)
        {
            // The ItemResponse object in the result represents the
            // created item.
            Console.WriteLine($"Upload complete, item ID: {uploadResult.ItemResponse.Id}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Upload failed");
        }
    }
    catch (ServiceException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading: {ex.ToString()}");
    }
}
```

> Here I am unsure what the maxSliceSize should be, the docs merely state that it should be a "Multiple of 320 KiB (320 * 1024)" ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.graph.largefileuploadtask-1.-ctor?view=graph-core-dotnet#Microsoft_Graph_LargeFileUploadTask_1__ctor_Microsoft_Graph_IUploadSession_System_IO_Stream_System_Int32_Microsoft_Graph_IBaseClient_)). Does this affect the performance in any way?

Code sample for download:

```
private IDriveRequestBuilder GetDrive()
{
    var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(_authenctication)
    return graphServiceClient.Sites[_oneDriveOptions.SiteId].Drive;
}

private async Task<Stream> GetPdf(string driveItemId)
{
    var pdfContentRequest = GetDrive().Items[driveItemId].Content.Request();
    pdfContentRequest.QueryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("format", "pdf"));
    var result = await pdfContentRequest.GetAsync();
    return result;
}
```

> Is 10-15s a reasonable amount of time to process both requests? I would guess this would be much faster if doing in memory but we haven't found any good enough library for conversion that suits our needs so we are currently stuck with the current approach. Maybe uploading/downloading to Onedrive adds a lot of overhead?

Comment: How long time does it take to open the document in a local _Microsoft Word_ instance and save it as PDF?

Comment: Did you measure time in each step?

Comment: @Gustav, is that a fair comparison? In my mind a lot of other overhead is added locally, such as hadnling UI stuff, opening a PDF-reader etc. But when testing this a document takes a couple of seconds to convert.

Comment: @JózefPodlecki, yup, I'd say the requests are around 50-50 in the amount of time it takes. Somewhere around 4-8 seconds each.

Comment: @KJ, yeah, I guess some form of file admin overhead is the thief here, but I just want to make sure we are not doing anything stupid. Still a bit unsure about the MaxSliceSize for instance. Ideally there would be one endpoint for converting PDFs so that overhead of two separate requests could be avoided.

Comment: _is that a fair comparison?_ ... not directly, but it could indicate the complexity of the document and, as I guess the local engine is quite fast, the minimum time to expect for the conversion.

Comment: Slice Size will affect your upload network performance. The best number requires evaluating your system's network stack, Internet speed, and behavior. Typically, performance rises rapidly to about 256 KB and then does not make much difference above 1 MB (the performance curve flattens).